# Google drive video: Color distortion

Tags: google-chrome, drive

I uploaded some videos to google drive recently. When playing the videos in the browser, the colors seem changed. Downloading the video and playing it on my local machine is again fine...so I guess this is drive/browser related. Anyone experienced the same? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had to **disable** `hardware acceleration` for chrome. Basically solution 1 of this guide:

https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-green-and-purple-vidoes-on-google-chrome/

Screenshot for convenience (**Menu > Settings > Advanced**):
[image]